# How to get report + score from Pylint when run Python code?

Tags: python, output, report, pylint

I can't seem to get any return value when running pylint from Python code directly. Running it from the command line generates a nice report, with a summarized score at the bottom.

I've tried putting the return value of "Run" into a variable, and getting it's "reports" field - but it looks like some default template.

this is what I have:

```
from io import StringIO
from pylint.reporters import text
from pylint.lint import Run


def main():
    print("I will verify you build!")
    pylint_opts = ['--rcfile=pylintrc.txt', '--reports=n', 'utilities']
    pylint_output = StringIO()
    reporter = text.TextReporter(pylint_output)
    Run(pylint_opts, reporter=reporter, do_exit=False)
    print(pylint_output.read())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'd expect some report here, but all I get is:
"
I will verify you build!

Process finished with exit code 0
"

Comment: What is the command you entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated the pylint issue. We ended up keeping current behavior because your code works with a slight adjustment:

```
def main():
    print("I will verify you build!")
    pylint_opts = ['--rcfile=pylintrc.txt', '--reports=n', 'utilities']
    pylint_output = StringIO()
    reporter = text.TextReporter(pylint_output)
    Run(pylint_opts, reporter=reporter, do_exit=False)
    print(pylint_output.getvalue())
```

[StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) is a stream that doesn't hide the stream position. Pylint writes to `pylint_output` correctly, but leaves the cursor at the end of the stream. `pylint_output.read()` only reads starting at the cursor.

You can call `pylint_output.seek(0)` to reset the stream position before calling `pylint_output.read()`. Alternatively, as demonstrated in the code block above, `StringIO` offers a method `getvalue` which will return the entire contents of the buffer regardless of cursor position.

The Pylint documentation will be updated with this example, so thanks for raising it.

Answer (score 1):

The code is alright but this is a bug in pylint that will be addressed by [this issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/5295).