# How to run pylint from inside Python?

Tags: python, pylint

I want to run pylint on all my modules, which are in different locations in a big directory. Because running pylint in this directory is [still not supported](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/352), I assume I need to walk through each module in my own Python scripts and run pylint on each module from there.

To run pylint inside a Python script, [the documentation](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#invoking-pylint) seems clear:

> It is also possible to call Pylint from another Python program, thanks
> to the `Run()` function in the `pylint.lint` module (assuming Pylint
> options are stored in a list of strings `pylint_options`) as:
>
> ```
> import pylint.lint
> pylint_opts = ['--version']
> pylint.lint.Run(pylint_opts)
> ```

However, I cannot get this to run successfully on actual files. What is the correct syntax? Even if I copy-paste the arguments that worked on the command-line, using an absolute file path, the call fails:

```
import pylint.lint 
pylint_opts = ["--load-plugins=pylint.extensions.docparams /home/user/me/mypath/myfile.py"]
pylint.lint.Run(pylint_opts)
```

The output is the default fallback dialogue of the command-line tool, with my script's name instead of pylint:

```
No config file found, using default configuration
Usage: myscript.py [options] module_or_package

  Check that a module satisfied a coding standard (and more !).

    myscript.py --help`  
[...]
```

What am I missing?

I know that `epylint` exists as an alternative, and I can get that to run, but it is extremely inconvenient that it overrides the `--msg-format` and `--reports` parameters and I want to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you include the actual output? That makes it more searchable for anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: There is no specific error output, only the "default" error message when parameters could not be parsed correctly. I will add the snippet to help search engine visibility. Thanks for the edits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking Pylint programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028268/invoking-pylint-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to separate the options into a list, as shown in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081299/how-to-get-report-score-from-pylint-when-run-python-code):

```
pylint_opts = ["--load-plugins=pylint.extensions.docparams", "/home/user/me/mypath/myfile.py"]
```

Comment: The clue was _"a list of strings"_, the API probably wouldn't require a list if it would always have only a single item in.